# unable to access jquery data set within ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some thing like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: my_url,
    success: function(data) {

        $('#some_div').data('test', 'This is a test');

    }
});
```

Then outside of the success callback, I tried to access my test variable like

```
console.debug($('#some_div').data('test'));
```

But this returns `undefined`

Any help please

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! That didn't happen yet.

Comment: it not how asynchronous requests work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiar yourself with the `$.ajax` `.done()` and `.fail()` methods.

**jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {});**
An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.

**jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});**
An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

[More Info Here!](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

The success function happens AFTER the request returns successfully.

Your console.debug line happens immediately after you make the $.ajax call, i.e. before the value it's inspecting gets set by the ajax success callback:

1. `$('#some_div').data('test')` is undefined
2. ajax call is made
3. `$('#some_div').data('test')` is still undefined!
4. Your console.debug line runs
5. `$('#some_div').data('test')` is still undefined...
6. Your ajax call returns sucessfully; `$('#some_div').data('test')` gets defined now

Yes, this is the most simple example of how asynchronous logic works, hence the comments you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the result in a global variable, i.e:

```
var globalVariable;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: my_url,
    success: function(data) {

        $('#some_div').data('test', 'This is a test');
        globalVariable = data;
    }
});
```

Storing things in the global scope isn't the best idea, so I'd recommend wrapping it in a [Self-Executing Anonymous Function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) to avoid poluting the global scope.

(Note: there are better ways of doing it, but avoiding complicating it too much)

Comment: `$('#some_div').data('test', 'This is a test');` is globally available.

Comment: @KevinB But the data that's returned to the success function is not.

Comment: right... he's using 'this is a test' as a test. he's obviously passing `data` there instead in reality.

Comment: My point is there's nothing wrong with how he's currently storing the data. The problem is *when* he is accessing the data, which your answer doesn't address.